# In this bit of code I am having a warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]. How can I fix this?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

```
int Linkedlist::count_value_type(Node* head_ptr, const Node::value_type& target)
{
    Node* current;
    int total = 0;

    for(current = head_ptr; current !=NULL; current = current->getLink())
    {
        if(target == current->getData())
        {
            ++total;
        }

    return 0;
    }
}
```

The code is based on a bunch of link list pointing to characters while another class stores the data in this class

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The problem is that, if `head_ptr` is null, the for loop will be skipped, and there won't be a return statement. So put the `return 0;` one line lower.

Answer (score 2):

***Why*** do you have that `return 0` *inside* the `for` loop?

The compiler is completely right. If `current == NULL` at the start of the `for` loop, the entire loop would be skipped, and no `return` would be executed, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Anyway, if that would compile, you'ld have had **serious** and **difficult** bugs there after. Sacred them be `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and `-Werror`!

You probably wanted to have that `return 0` *after* the `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what the loop is doing exactly, but you must know it's not a good idea to have 'return' statements inside loops.  It's best to just break out of the loop instead, and do your 'return' lines outside of it, like this:

```
for(...) {
    if(target != current->getData())
        break;

    total++;
}

return total;
```

This should fix your warning among other things.  Also note that I inverted the if() conditional to trigger the 'break' bit.

Comment: :"one return statement per function" is an anti-pattern in C++.  Maybe it works well in other languages (which don't have stack unwinding) but in C++ it just causes more bugs.  Returning inside a loop is fine, if you're ready to exit the function.

Comment: I don't remember advocating one-return-per-function though, I do multiple early-returns myself.  However, in my opinion, returns inside loops is one of those things you should do when you know exactly what you're doing (like being ready to exit as you pointed out).